# Dot Net Nuke 5.0 - Good pages with lots of examples of each modules

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke 5.0 and want to find a good website with obvious examples of each of the standard modules and how to configure them. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest that you spend some time on the dotnetnuke site itself, including the forumns, also do take a good luck are dnncreative magazine site, it is excellent.  The main bloggers on the dnn site also have excellent personal sites, no point in listing them here, just review the bloggers and you will find loads of info on their site.

Finally, the best and easiest way to learn DNN is to play with it yourself.  Get your PC set up so that you aren trash and re-install in 5 minutes and the play with it, experiment with downloading and installing from free modules and read, read read.  There is lots of info available and you just have to google and you will find.

Start and www.dotnetnuke.com and enjoy, I love it,

Mark Breen
Ireland